# How do annotations prevent mutations of an array parameter?

Tags: java, arrays, annotations, immutability

I understand that annotations are immutable, however, arrays in Java are by themselves not immutable. After running a test I notice that the array returned from an annotation parameter can be mutated but it does not effect the source array:

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface ArrayAnnotation {
    String[] value() default {};
}

@ArrayAnnotation({"foo"})
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayAnnotation test = Main.class.getAnnotation(ArrayAnnotation.class);

        String[] test0 = test.value();
        test0[0] = "bar";
        System.out.println(test0[0]);

        String[] test1 = test.value();
        System.out.println(test1[0]);
    }
}
```

This prints:

```
bar
foo
```

What is going on behind the scenes here? Is there simply an array copy happening during each call to `value()`, or is it something more complex?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Is there simply an array copy happening during each call to value(), or is it something more complex?

Yes, the array is copied.

---

Annotations are a special kind of `interface` type. ([JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6))

They are implemented by some [`Proxy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) classes at runtime. 
You can debug it if you set breakpoint at `Proxy.newProxyInstance()`.

Invocations on annotation are intercepted by [`AnnotationInvocationHandler`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/7ac414640ad5/src/java.base/share/classes/sun/reflect/annotation/AnnotationInvocationHandler.java#l88) which copies arrays:

```
if (result.getClass().isArray() && Array.getLength(result) != 0)
     result = cloneArray(result);
```

Comment: Ah, very cool! The step-into feature in my IDE's debugger wasn't triggering anything for `values()` but adding a breakpoint directly in the `AnnotationInvocationHandler` proxy does the trick! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

You are right, it returns a copy each time to ensure it is not changed.

In a future version of Java, this copy might be optimised away.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking that it seems pretty expensive to copy the array every time that it is viewed!